# Admob How to set up App-ads.txt associated domain

Tags: admob

App-ads.txt seems simple enough to set up, but I noticed in my Admob account that I have no App-ads.txt URLs for any of my apps. I'm not sure why or how I add that. I have a privacy policy link from that url in appstore connect, as well as a contact page from the same url but admob doesn't see these links as my url.

I can't see anywhere in appstore connect to just add a url that is associated with that app. Not sure how it's done on android either.

Comment: I am having the same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jackson Nope.....nobody replied so I guess nobody knows.

Comment: Check out my solution.

Comment: Ok I didn't have the marketing URL set, maybe that's it. Not sure why Google don't tell you that anywhere though.

Comment: Yeah I agree it took me months to figure that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the marketing URL is set for your app in AppStore Connect. I confirmed that this is the URL Google uses to look for your ads.txt file.

Comment: I noticed that all my apps that showed the ads.txt file correctly had a marketing URL and all of the ones that don't show my ads.txt file don't have a marketing URL. Since the marketing URL is optional in AppStore Connect I' surprised that Goolge uses it as the "official" associated URL but I think they do.